# SharePoint 2010 Organizational Browser Web Part on non-My-site Claims Based start at a defined username

Tags: 2010, organization-browser, claims

SharePoint 2010 Organizational Browser Web Part on non-MySite Claims Web Application.

It's been used for the intranet and to help display organization charts.

To get this working first of all I needed to use the following JavaScript mention in the below KB because of the use of Claims.

SharePoint 2010: Organization Browser web part does not render for Windows Claims users
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643420

This all works as expected.

Unfortunately, my client's requirement is to now specify which user is the start location in the Organization chart and not just the user that is hitting the page.

This can be done through the use of the following:

http://www.tcscblog.com/2011/07/29/start-the-organization-browser-at-any-account-name/

Unfortunately, it seems a combination of the two together results in the Organizational Browser not loading at all!

Has anyone accomplished starting the Organizational Browser at a different username on a Claims Based Application

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 you could do this by embedding an iframe HTML element with src pointing to the other user's OrganizationView.aspx page such as https://mysite.contoso.com/OrganizationView.aspx?accountname=CONTOSO%5CBradS&IsDlg=1. However, SharePoint 2013 is more restrictive and prohibits **cross-origin resource sharing**, so this approach will break when you upgrade.